# Trying to add buttons to dynamic sub-menu with insertBefore results in "Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 2 is not of type 'Node'"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to dynamically add buttons to toggle the visibility of sub-menus in a navigation system. The idea being if a user created a sub-menu in the CMS, JavaScript would dynamically add a button above this at the same level as the sub-menu's parent

element to allow content to be toggled.

So static HTML like this

```
<nav>
  <ul class="primary-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">nav item
    <!-- sub menu-->
      <ul class="child-nav">
        <li class="child-nav-item">child nav item</li>
        <li class="child-nav-item">child nav item</li>
        <li class="child-nav-item">child nav item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">nav item
    <!-- sub menu-->
      <ul class="child-nav">
        <li class="child-nav-item">child nav item</li>
        <li class="child-nav-item">child nav item</li>
        <li class="child-nav-item">child nav item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Would be dynamically changed to something like the mark-up below, with the button to toggle visibility of the sub-menu appearing above the sub-menu's  element

```
<nav>
  <ul class="primary-nav">
     <li class="nav-item">nav item
     <button>Show show menu</button>
     <!-- sub menu -->
       <ul class="child-nav">
         <li class="child-nav-item">child nav item</li>
         <li class="child-nav-item">child nav item</li>
         <li class="child-nav-item">child nav item</li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">nav item
      <button>Show sub menu</button>
        <!-- sub menu -->
       <ul class="child-nav">
         <li class="child-nav-item">child nav item</li>
         <li class="child-nav-item">child nav item</li>
         <li class="child-nav-item">child nav item</li>
       </ul>
     </li>
 </ul>
</nav>`
```

However when I use querySelectorAll and insertBefore I get the following error message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 2 is not of type 'Node'.
```

The code below results in the error:

```
const navItem = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-item");
const subNav = document.querySelectorAll(".child-nav");

const button = document.createElement("button");
button.textContent = "sub-menu";

// add button if sub-menu is present
for (i = 0; i < navItem.length; i++ ) {
  if (navItem[i].hasChildNodes() === true)  {
    navItem[i].insertBefore(button, subNav);
  }
}
```

However if I use querySelector(".child-nav") as below and amend navItem[i] to navItem[0] what I hoped to happen does, that is the button is added, obviously though this is only added to the first element and I need it to be added above all the the sub-menu  elements if present.

```
const navItem = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-item");
const subNav = document.querySelector(".child-nav");

// add button if sub-menu is present
for (i = 0; i < navItem.length; i++ ) {
  if (navItem[i].hasChildNodes() === true)  {
    navItem[0].insertBefore(button, subNav);
  }
}
```

Can anyone help? I'm completely stumped.

I've tried swapping querySelectorAll(".child-nav") for getElementsByClassName("child-nav") thus switching from a nodeList to a HTMLCollection but I still get the error message about parameter 2 not being a node, though everything works fine if I just use querySelector.

Comment: querySelectorAll(".child-nav") returns a nodeList, you should loop over it to add the element to each node in the nodeList

Comment: So what is unclear about getting an error when providing a `nodeList` or a `HTMLCollection` when a `node` is expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rewrite your code like this (the Javascript part).

```js
const navItem = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-item");
//const subNav = document.querySelector(".child-nav"); <== not here

// add button if sub-menu is present
for (i = 0; i < navItem.length; i++ ) {
  if (navItem[i].hasChildNodes() === true)  {
    //navItem[i].insertBefore(button, subNav); <== not here
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.textContent = "sub-menu";
   
    var subNav = navItem[i].querySelector(".child-nav");
    navItem[i].insertBefore(button,subNav);
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="primary-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">nav item
    <!-- sub menu-->
      <ul class="child-nav">
        <li class="child-nav-item">child nav item</li>
        <li class="child-nav-item">child nav item</li>
        <li class="child-nav-item">child nav item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">nav item
    <!-- sub menu-->
      <ul class="child-nav">
        <li class="child-nav-item">child nav item</li>
        <li class="child-nav-item">child nav item</li>
        <li class="child-nav-item">child nav item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

You'll notice that Ive removed the `button` and `subnav` definitions to be inside the for loop. The reason for this is:

- each of the `buttons` you want to add to your navigation are separate DOM elements, and should be unique, even if their appearance and background code is the same. Think of it like this - let's say that your button is a person. With the original code, it would be as if you were trying to tell that person to be at multiple places at the same time
- things are similar for the `subnav` - we are checking the children of the current `navitem`, and attaching the button before any of them

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer @FiddlingAway it's brilliant! I thought the solution would be something like this, but could 'see' how it might work...

I noticed there was no ' for loop for querySelector('.child-nav') so I'm guessing a loop isn't needed because the for loop iterates through each instance of nav-item then applies the button to each child-nav element at a node level? Which solves the original problem..

Comment: @NathanWind That is correct - the `for` loop isn't needed for your `.child-nav-item` collection, because you're just getting the parents, and saying something like "Take this newly created shiny button, and place it as the first thing, before your other children".

Answer (score -1):

Try using AppendChild or Prepend.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).